# getCharIndexAtPoint() equivalent in Spark RichEditableText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I want to find a way to get the character index in a Spark  based RichEditableText based on mouse x, y position.

The  mx.controls.TextArea has a protected getCharIndexAtPoint() method but I  can't find an equivalent of this in the Spark RichEditableText which is  disappointing.

Any  ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I can see why. seems RichEditableText uses FTE, while TextArea uses TextField, so you can just use [TextField::getCharIndexAtPoint](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharIndexAtPoint%28%29). you may just as well have no char at a point.

It's a long time since I've had a a look at FTE, but I think [TextLine::getAtomIndexAtPoint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/engine/TextLine.html#getAtomIndexAtPoint%28%29) would be a good start. Also, you should have a look at [TLFTextField::getCharIndexAtPoint](http://www.airia.cn/FLEX4API/livedocs/flashx/textLayout/controls/TLFTextField.html#getCharIndexAtPoint%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution after the heads up from back2dos i came up with the following solution, probably needs a bit of work but it functions

http://www.justinpante.net/?p=201

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used:

```
private function getCharAtPoint(ta:RichEditableText, x:Number, y:Number) : int 
{

    var globalPoint:Point = ta.localToGlobal(new Point(x, y));

    var flowComposer:IFlowComposer = ta.textFlow.flowComposer;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < flowComposer.numLines; i++){ 

        var textFlowLine:TextFlowLine = flowComposer.getLineAt(i);

        if (y >= textFlowLine.y && y < textFlowLine.height + textFlowLine.y)
        {
            return textFlowLine.absoluteStart 
                 + textFlowLine.getTextLine(true)
                     .getAtomIndexAtPoint(globalPoint.x, globalPoint.y);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The answer Even Mien gave did not work for me, initially.

With the below changes I got it working.

```
        var globalPoint:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);

        var flowComposer:IFlowComposer = this.textFlow.flowComposer;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < flowComposer.numLines; i++)
        { 
            var textFlowLine:TextFlowLine = flowComposer.getLineAt(i);
            var textLine:TextLine = textFlowLine.getTextLine(true);
            var textRect:Rectangle = textLine.getRect(stage);

            if (globalPoint.y >= textRect.top && globalPoint.y < textRect.bottom)
            {
                return textFlowLine.absoluteStart + textLine.getAtomIndexAtPoint(globalPoint.x, globalPoint.y);
            }
        }

        return 0;
```